# Maven plugins to analyze javascript code quality

Tags: javascript, maven-2, static-analysis, jslint

Javascript code can be tough to maintain.
I am looking for tools that will help me ensure a reasonable quality level.
So far I have found [JsUNit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit), a very nice unit test framework for javascript. Tests can be run automatically from ant on any browser available.
I have not found yet some javascript equivalent of PMD, checkstyle, Findbug...

Do you know any static code analysis tool for javascript ?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to make sense. What does maven have to do with JavaScript quality control?

Comment: Fixed the title.  Also, Maven has a lot to do with quality control over any source code and because it can automatically and consistently pump out builds and synchronized quality reports for developers from desktops and CI servers.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old thread, but if you're interested in running Jasmine for BDD testing in your maven project, I wrote this jasmine-maven-plugin for exactly this purpose (that is, improving JS quality by encouraging TDD of it).

http://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin

Answer (score 11):

I've used the following code to run JSLint as part of the COMPILE phase in Maven.

It downloads jslint4java from maven repository so you don't need anything else.

If JSLint found problems in javascript files, the build will fail.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <taskdef name="jslint" classname="com.googlecode.jslint4java.ant.JSLintTask" classpath="${settings.localRepository}/com/googlecode/jslint4java/jslint4java-ant/1.4.2/jslint4java-ant-1.4.2.jar" />
                            <jslint options="white,browser,devel,undef,eqeqeq,plusplus,bitwise,regexp,strict,newcap,immed">
                                <predef>Ext,Utils</predef>
                                <formatter type="plain" />
                                <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/js" includes="**/*.js" />
                            </jslint>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.googlecode.jslint4java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jslint4java-ant</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

[Wro4j-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/MavenPlugin) provides several goals for static code analysis for JavaScript and CSS resources as well, like: [jslint](http://jslint.com/), [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) and [csslint](http://csslint.net/)

Here is a link to the official [Wro4j-maven-plugin documentation](https://wro4j.readthedocs.io/en/stable/MavenPlugin/).

Answer (score 4):

A couple of plugins I've submitted at Codehaus may also be of interest:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/js-import-maven-plugin/

http://mojo.codehaus.org/jslint-maven-plugin/

The first one brings Maven dependency management to JavaScript. The second one allows the rapid and efficient invocation of JSLint.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google for "jslint ant task" reveals [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/), which apparently includes an Ant task.

Comment: The jslint4java ant task should be fairly easy to embed in maven using the antrun plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This project looks close:

http://dev.abiss.gr/mvn-jstools/index.html

It generates a report with JsLint.  It doesn't look like it hooks into the test phase of the build lifecycle, so I don't think it will reject a build if jslint finds issues (which is what I'd like to do on my projects).

Answer (score 1):

jslint4java has been mentioned a few times, I can't recall which version they added it, but there's actually a built in Maven task.

Traditionally with jslint4java and Maven, folks have used the antrun plugin to run the jslint4java ant task, however you can now configure it all in Maven and avoid that extra step.

http://docs.jslint4java.googlecode.com/git/2.0.2/maven.html

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on the [SweetDEV RIA project](http://sweetdev-ria.sourceforge.net/) which is a Java tag library composed of several "Web 2.0/Ajax/JavaScript" components.

The maven 2 build process includes some in-house plugins which launches [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) (code verifier), [JsMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) (code minifier), [JsDoc generation](http://sweetdev-ria.sourceforge.net/sweetdev-ria3.1/jsdoc/index.html) (JavaDoc like documentation), [JsUnit](http://www.jsunit.net/) (unit tests) and [Selenium](http://selenium.openqa.org/) (in browser) tests .

You may take a look on [the SweetDEV RIA maven plugins repository](http://sweetdev-ria.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sweetdev-ria/sweetdev-ria-m2-plugins/trunk/).

Comment: Could you edit your answer and fix the broken link at the end? And replace `jsunit.net` link with https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit (the jsunit.net domain has been taken by an ad company)

Answer (score 0):

The new [jslint-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jslint-maven-plugin) looks useful. It wraps jslint4java, executing JSLint during the test phase of your build.

Answer (score -1):

Sonar and the JavaScript Plugin: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JavaScript+Plugin

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more specific with you answer quoting and reasoning about the provided link.