# Can maven-exec-plugin fail the build?

Tags: maven-2

I have a maven execution that runs a javascript compressor as a command line program, however, this tool also does some jslint checks as well.

If these jslint checks fail so should my build.

These errors are output as a parseable string to stdout.

If this maven plugin cannot solve this problem, I'm happy to use any other suggested.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To my knowledge, [`exec:exec`](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) will fail the build **if** the return code of the executed command is not `0` (or one of the configured [`successCodes`](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#successCodes)). Maybe you can build something around this.

As an alternative, have a look at these plugins, they both can fail a build on problems:

- the [Jslint Maven Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jslint-maven-plugin/)
- the [YUI Compressor Maven Mojo](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/index.html)

Depending on what you need exactly, there is also the [Maven Javascript Plugin](http://javascript-maven.softec.lu/javascript-maven-plugin/index.html).

And also have a look at this [Maven plugins for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92372/maven-plugins-for-javascript) question.

Comment: This works great, I was running running a .bat file that was swallowing the exit code.