# rpm build prevention when there are syntactic errors in perl/shell script

Tags: shell, perl, maven, build, pom.xml

We package only Perl and shell scripts in an rpm.We use maven to build the rpm.
I would like to know if there is a way to prevent the rpm from compiling successfully when there are syntax errors in the perl/shell scripts.

C/C++/Java code does not get compiled when there are syntax errors, this also prevents the rpm from getting built successfully.
Perl/shell being interpreted does not work this way.Is there a way to handle this in pom/Maven?

Comment: You should have tests for your perl/shell code...which is a step before packaging an RPM...

Answer (score 0):

You can use, as mentioned in "[I want to execute shell commands from maven's pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3493919/6309)", the [**`exec-maven-plugin`**](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to execute a command.

In your case, that command could be a script in charge of

- compiling / checking the syntax of perl scripts
- returning *not* 0 if there is any compilation/syntax error: see "[Can `maven-exec-plugin` fail the build?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481297/6309)"

Add that step before the one compiling `npm`, and said `npm` compilation won't be executed unless the perl syntax checks out.